# How to get UINavigation controller from Tabbar controller and push a specific view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am trying to implement `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method. When I receive a push notification I want to show a specific view. My app is using `UITabbarController` as root view controller and `UINavigationController` as its children:

[image: storyboard]

and here is my appdelegate:

```
 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
        UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)[[((UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController) viewControllers] objectAtIndex:2];
        NSString * storyboardName = @"others";
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
        UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BusinessAccountView"];
        [navController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
        [PFPush handlePush:userInfo];
}
```

Unfortunately the code does not work. It works if I change `[navController pushViewController:vc animated:YES]` to `[navController presentViewController:vc animated:YES]`, but I will lose my navigation bar. 
Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Comment: Instead of getting `navController` from `objectAtIndex:2`, try using `selectedViewController` to get the currently displayed navigation controller. Does it work?

Comment: Or try setting `tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2` before pushing the view controller. Does this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a stepwise solution.

- First check if the **tab** on which you want to push the view controller is already selected. If not, use `setSelectedIndex` or `setSelectedViewController` to select that tab first.
- Next, get the `rootViewController` (your `UINavigationController`) of the tabBarController's selected view controller.
- Next, instantiate the viewController you want to push, and push it on the navController.

Sample code:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

    UITabBarController* tabController = self.window.rootViewController;
    if (tabController.selectedIndex != 2) [tabController setSelectedIndex:2];



    UINavigationController *navController = tabController.selectedViewController;
    NSString * storyboardName = @"others";
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BusinessAccountView"];
    [navController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
    [PFPush handlePush:userInfo];
}
```

Comment: It works great! How come I didnt find this solution when searching stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Follow this tutorial (Storyboard Tutorial: Create Tab Bar Controller and Web View)....

http://www.appcoda.com/storyboard-tutorial-create-tab-bar-controller-and-web-view/

Comment: This should be a comment. Not an answer.

Comment: This tutorial gives a simple example of building an app using Nav and Tab controller, but did not mentioned anything about my question.